# BETWEEN query with JPA and Metamodel

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I am trying to write a between query with JPA 2.

```
Integer zipCode = 50000;
CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Territory> query = builder.createQuery(Territory.class);
Metamodel m = getEntityManager().getMetamodel();

Root<Territory> root = query.from(Territory.class);

// zipCode between startZipCodeRange and endZipCodeRange
Predicate condition = builder.between(zipCode , root.get(Territory_.startZipCodeRange), root.get(Territory_.endZipCodeRange));
```

The final line does not compile because zipCode is not of type Expression.
Is it possible to convert zipCode to an Expression? If so, how would I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
root.get(Territory_.zipcode) as 1st parameter of between function if, Territory does have zipcode attribute.

See the comments on this answer for more details.

Comment: zipCode is an Integer value.  I want to get all values from the DB where 50000 is between the startZipCodeRange and end endZipCodeRange.

Comment: If this is the case, then you should use the following condition builder.and(builder.gt(root.get(Territory_.startZipCodeRange),50000), builder.lt(root.get(Territory_.endZipCodeRange),50000));

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I have ended up doing.  I am still not sure if it is possible with the between operator.